# Can I back up Windows 7's backup settings?

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-7-backup

I use Windows 7 backup and am about to reformat my PC.  After I run Windows 7 backup which backs up my files to another hard drive, I am going to reformat the main drive and reinstall Windows 7.  I have a complicated mapping of folders that I do and do not want Windows to back up and I don't feel like redoing it after the reinstall.  If at all possible, I'd like to back up the backup settings so that I can apply them to the new installation.  Is this possible?

Comment: Use Windows Easy Transfer to back up your settings, not sure if this backs up those particular settings or not. Great question.

Comment: I just used it to save my Windows settings.  I will come back in a few days to let you know if backup settings were saved with everything else.  If it works, I'll have you post that as the answer so I can mark it.

Comment: This does not work.  I guess I will have to wait until the next reformat to find out if a solution truly does exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the registry key where backup settings are stored. I think the sub key you want to backup is "ScheduleParams", possibly others, you may have to experiment.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsBackup

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb891959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This is exactly the key that stores the backup settings.  I tested this by first setting up all my folders. I then exported that registry key to a .reg file. After that, I modified the backup settings by selecting different folders. I refreshed the registry editor and saw the ScheduleParams keys change accordingly.  I opened Windows Backup again just to make sure my previous changes took.  After that, I imported the .reg file I previously exported, opened Windows Backup again, and everything was restored!  This will be a great piece of information to know on the next reinstall.  Thanks!